# cursor is null giving NPE

Tags: java, sqlite, android-layout, exception, android-cursor

I'm trying to retrieve data from a database via a cursor I get an NPE. I'm pretty sure data is being inserted into the database since I've used this same database for another android app with no problem. I've tried looking at answers for similar questions but none have solved my issue. Here is my code.

```
package com.example.testapp;
import mylibs.testshop;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.*;

public class shopping_list extends Activity {
   testshop shop;
   String item, type;
   int IdCounter = 0;
   LinearLayout itemLayout;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.shopping_list);
       shop = new testshop(this); // now Initialized shop
        showShoppinglist();
        }

   public void showShoppinglist() {
       itemLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_list);

       // Here's is the cursor that gives the NPE
       String[] columns = new String[] { testshop.TABLE_ROW_ID,
                                         testshop.TABLE_ROW_ONE, 
                                         testshop.TABLE_ROW_TWO };
       Cursor cursor = shop.db.rawQuery(testshop.TABLE_NAME, columns);

       cursor.moveToFirst();
       if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
          do {
              addItemToList(cursor);
          } 
          while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }
       cursor.close(); // closing of the cursor
       shop.db.close(); // closing the database
   }

   public void addItemToList(Cursor items) {
       RelativeLayout itemListlayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
       try {
           addItemToitemListLayout(itemListlayout,
                                   items.getString(1),
                                   items.getString(1));
       } 
       catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("additemtolistLAYOUT ERROR", e.toString());
       }
       itemListlayout.setId(IdCounter++);
       itemLayout.addView(itemListlayout);
   }

   private void addItemToitemListLayout(RelativeLayout itemListlayout,
                                        String string,
                                        String string2) {
       TextView textView = new TextView(this);
       textView.setText(item);
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutDesc = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       layoutDesc.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
       textView.setId(IdCounter++);
       TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
       textView2.setText(type);
       layoutDesc.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textView2.getId());
       textView2.setId(IdCounter++);
       itemListlayout.addView(textView, layoutDesc);
       itemListlayout.addView(textView2, layoutDesc);
   }
}
```

Here's my logcat :

```
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.shopping_list}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1579)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:66)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.example.testapp.shopping_list.showShoppinglist(shopping_list.java:38)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.example.testapp.shopping_list.onCreate(shopping_list.java:30)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-31 17:23:36.464: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: please read the documentation for `rawQuery`.

Comment: Is the rawQuery wrongly done? @njzk2

Comment: like I said, `please read the documentation for rawQuery.` It does not do what you think it does (or your variables are poorly named).

Comment: I've just read the documentation and From my understanding It is rawQuery(the name of the table I want to read from, the columns which I want to read data from);. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid you are, yes. The documentation reads `...Parameters
sql the SQL query...` a table name is not an SQL query.

Comment: It worked thankyou. I used query instead of rawQuery =D @njzk2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `shop` is `null`. You haven't initialized it.

Comment: When I initialize it I get string  index out of bounds exception                                                                         `shop = new testshop(this);//initialized here`

Comment: Then you should be fixing that

Comment: Fixing the string index out of bounds?